# Nested steps in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have a figure in a Beamer-presentation. I want to change the content of TikZ-boxes step-wise, and the box itself should also be a step. It sort of works, but I get an error-message. So I wonder how to do it correctly.
Log:

> ! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
>
> ! You can't use `\lastskip' in restricted horizontal mode.

MWE (maybe a bit large, but then you get to see what I try to accomplish):

```
\documentclass[14pt,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfpages,tikz,tikzsymbols}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzstyle{matnode} = [inner sep=0pt,outer
sep=0pt,anchor=base,remember picture]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Balance sheet of firm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\tikzstyle{sboxdef} = [  font={\small}, right=1cm,text width=2.1cm, rounded corners, inner sep=1ex, draw=black];

% Draw lines and titles for balance sheet
\node (start) at ($ (current page.south)!.85!(current page.north) $) {};
\node (end) at ($ (current page.south)!.20!(current page.north) $) {};

\node[shift={(-3.5cm,-0.5cm)}](Hstart) at ($ (current page.south)!.80!(current page.north) $) {};
\node[shift={(3.5cm,-0.5cm)}](Hend) at ($ (current page.south)!.80!(current page.north) $) {};

\draw[-,thick] (start)  --  (end);
\draw[-,thick] (Hstart)  --  (Hend);

\node[shift={(1.5cm,0.5cm)}](Htext1) at (Hstart){\textbf{Assets}};
\node[shift={(-1.5cm,0.5cm)}](Htext2) at (Hend){\textbf{Financed}};

% Content of asset-side of balance sheet.
% I need the first onslide because in the original slide I had more stuff prior to this. 
% I need onslide inside in order to take up space so that boxes remain the same (I think)
\onslide<1->{
    \node[shift={(-4.1cm,1.3cm)}](SAssets) at (current page.center)[sboxdef, text height=0.7cm, fill=red!20]{
        \onslide<1>{\textbf{Short\\ Assets}}\only<2->{\textbf{2573}}
    };
    
    \node[shift={(-4.1cm,-0.9cm)}](LAssets) at (current page.center)[sboxdef, text height=1.5cm, fill=red!20]{
        \onslide<1>{\textbf{Long\\ Assets}}\only<2->{\textbf{3876}}
    };
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes from the `\onslide` command, which I fixed. I also used the opportunity to clean up, replace `\tikzstyle` by the corresponding `\tikzset` syntax and to draw your attention to `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}`, which is made for these things.

```
\documentclass[14pt,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{matnode/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer
sep=0pt,anchor=base,remember picture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Balance sheet of firm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\tikzset{sboxdef/.style={font={\small}, right=1cm,text width=2.1cm, rounded
corners, inner sep=1ex, draw=black}}

% Draw lines and titles for balance sheet
\node (start) at ($ (current page.south)!.85!(current page.north) $) {};
\node (end) at ($ (current page.south)!.20!(current page.north) $) {};
% 
\node[shift={(-3.5cm,-0.5cm)}](Hstart) at ($ (current page.south)!.80!(current page.north) $) {};
\node[shift={(3.5cm,-0.5cm)}](Hend) at ($ (current page.south)!.80!(current page.north) $) {};
% 
\draw[-,thick] (start)  --  (end);
\draw[-,thick] (Hstart)  --  (Hend);
% 
\node[shift={(1.5cm,0.5cm)}](Htext1) at (Hstart){\textbf{Assets}};
\node[shift={(-1.5cm,0.5cm)}](Htext2) at (Hend){\textbf{Financed}};
% 
% % Content of asset-side of balance sheet.
% % I need the first onslide because in the original slide I had more stuff prior to this. 
% % I need onslide inside in order to take up space so that boxes remain the same (I think)
\node[shift={(-4.1cm,1.3cm)},visible
on=<1->,align=center](SAssets) at (current page.center)[sboxdef,
text height=0.7cm, fill=red!20]{%
        \only<1>{\textbf{Short}\\ \textbf{Assets}}\only<2->{\textbf{2573}}
    };

\node[shift={(-4.1cm,-0.9cm)},visible
on=<1->,align=center](LAssets) at (current page.center)[sboxdef,
text height=1.5cm, fill=red!20]{%
        \only<1>{\textbf{Long}\\ \textbf{Assets}}\only<2->{\textbf{3876}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and other input. I used the `\onslide` for the first text/step in order to take up space so that boxes doesn't change size (you can imagine that the size of the boxes should represent the numbers). Using `\only ` would be good if I knew how fix the heigth of the box.